# jQuery cleditor plugin: creating a new button

Tags: jquery-plugins, cleditor

Using [cleditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/), I'm trying to set up a custom button with the following code:

```
(function($) {
    $.cleditor.buttons.link_species = {
        name: "link_species",
        image: "fish.gif",
        title: "Species Link",
        command: "inserthtml",
        popupName: "link_species",
        popupClass: "cleditorPrompt",
        popupContent: "Genus: <input type='text' size='15'> Species: <input type='text' size='15'><br />Remove italics? <input type='checkbox' value='remove'>&nbsp;<input type='button' value='Ok' />",
        buttonClick: link_speciesClick
    };

  // Handle the hello button click event
  function link_speciesClick(e, data) {
    // Wire up the submit button click event
    $(data.popup).children(":button")
      .unbind("click")
      .bind("click", function(e) {

        // Get the editor
        var editor = data.editor;

        var $text = $(data.popup).find(":text"),
          genus = $text[0].value,
          species = $text[1].value;

        var slug = genus + '-' + species;
        slug = htmlEntities(slug);

        var link = '/dev/species/' + slug + '/';
        var rel = link + '?preview=true';

        var display = firstUpper(genus) + ' ' + species;

        // Get the entered name
        var html = '<a href="' + link + '" rel="' + rel + '">' + display + '</a>';

        if ( !$(data.popup).find(":checkbox").is(':checked') ) {
            html = '<em>' + html + '</em>';
        }

        // Insert some html into the document
        editor.execCommand(data.command, html, null, data.button);

        // Hide the popup and set focus back to the editor
        editor.hidePopups();
        editor.focus();
      });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

It's a WordPress website, and the directory structure is something like this:

`/wp-content/plugins/sf-species-profile/cleditor`

Within there I have all the cleditor files and `config.js`.This file is where the above code is stored.

I also have an `images` folder containing a 24*24 `fish.gif` file.

For some reason, when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
[firefox]
a is undefined
<<myurl>>/wp-content/plugins/sf-species-profiles/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.min.js?ver=3.3.1
Line 17

[chrome]
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

If I change the "image" argument to image:"" the same image for "B" appears, but the plugin works without error.

Does anyone have any ideas what may be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to debug with the non minimized version. You can get it from here: http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/ ([zip](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/downloads/CLEditor1_3_0.zip))

There are 2 functions that include a length call in the code that ends up in line 17 of the minimized code. One in the function hex(s) that processes color. The other is the the imagePath function.

```
function imagesPath() {
  var cssFile = "jquery.cleditor.css",
  href = $("link[href$='" + cssFile +"']").attr("href");
  return href.substr(0, href.length - cssFile.length) + "images/";
}
```

It could throw an error of the type you have if your rendered html doesn't include a line like "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/jquery.cleditor.css" />". (Href would then be undefined.)

For wordpress integration, you may find it easier to setup when using the [wordpress plugin version of cleditor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cleditor-for-wordpress/).

Comment: Hi widged, thanks for your post - that's good thinking! The exact error, using the full JS file, is this: `href is undefined: return href.substr(0, href.length - cssFile.length) + "images/";`. So, you're exactly right, but it doesn't appear to be to do with the CSS file - that's linked correctly. Any other ideas?

Comment: Aahhhhh, it WAS the css file! When I delved into how `link[href$=...` worked, I realised that it would only find the CSS file if it ended `jquery.cleditor.css`. WordPress naturally adds `?ver=3.3.1` to the end of enqueued stylesheets, so when I removed that, the problem was resolved!